# NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I suddenly get hundreds of these lines in my console log running a process which uses a progress controller I implemented:

```
** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7afafd0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xd8ca4a0 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I'm in a multithreaded environment on iPhone Simulator, downloading a file from the web using WebClient(). I am puzzled how to deal with this as I have no idea what might cause the problem. The thread that is running the download is embedded in

```
using ( var oAutoRelease = new NSAutoreleasePool (  ) )
```

I'm attaching to the WebClient's `DownloadProgressChanged` method and in there I call a delegate which updates the progress view. If I remove this line, the warnings are gone:

```
ProgressInfo(ACTION.ReceivingResponse, e.ProgressPercentage);
```

Calling the delegate in turns will go back to my progress controller and udpate a label:

```
// iIndicator = the value of e.ProgressPercentage.
oProgressController.CurrentActivity = "Percentage done: " + iInidicator.ToString (  ) + "%";
// ProgressController.CurrentActivity:
this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate { this.oLblCurrentActivity.Text = value; });
```

What am I missing here!?

**EDIT:** I figured out that I had to put another NSAutoReleasePool() around  `this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate { this.oLblCurrentActivity.Text = value; });`
But why? The whole thing is already in a separate pool.

Comment: Something wasn't in a pool, probably a callback from an async method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link should help you http://blog.datispars.com/tasks-in-background-thread-cocoa-performselectorinbackground/
Each thread should have it's own autorelease pool

Comment: As of Monotouch 5.2 no auto release pools in threads are required anymore! All automatic now!